# innerHTML bug IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml, innerhtml

This innerHTML code wasn't working reliably in IE8:
(but was working in IE6 IE7 FF Opera Chrome Safari)
(by not working reliably I mean I had placed this code within onmouseover handlers on various elements, sometimes it would change the text when mousing over a given element and sometimes it wouldn't - there was no pattern to this - whether it would work or not seemed to be totally random)

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML="some text";
```

DOM methods (removing and re-adding the div with updated text) weren't helping either.

So I added this immediately after the above code and it fixed it:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule("#mydiv:after", "content: ' ';");
```

Using conditional comments I identified this 2nd line of code as for IE8 only

I am positive this will save people a lot of time since I have wasted ages on this!
Even `Jquery.text()` wasn't helping!

I have read elsewhere that the innerHTML will update the DOM but can fail to update screen elements. I believe the CSS rule works because it changes the content of the after pseudo class of #mydiv dynamically and thus requires the content of mydiv to be updated, thus updating the screen (something innerHTML was failing to do).

However if anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear - Thanks

EDITED AS REQUESTED

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you specify what "not working reliably" means in this context? Why does the CSS rule fix whatever doesn't work? Bug reports and fixes are well and good but they need some groundwork.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't have any duplicate id's or anything? Do you know that `getElementById("mydiv")` is actually returning the correct DOMElement?

Answer (score -1):

You can use innerText in place of innerHTML

Comment: ```innerText``` isn't cross browser friendly - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html.